# Why have I only found items as high as level 61 even though I am now level 66?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've played Act V up to Urzael, leveling my monk to 66 at the boss kill.  The highest item level of any item I've found is level 61.  I would have expected to find higher level items at this point.

Is this by design?  **Why am I not finding items higher than level 61?**

Comment: I'd say it's really just bad luck... I've found many Items that exactly match my level. What difficulty are you playing on? And also check blue items for their level (you don't have to keep them)

Comment: Have you found items that match your level between 61 and 66?  Were they legendary/set or rare/magic/white?

Comment: As you can See [my character](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/profile/Jutschge-2989/hero/773037) has some level 66 yellow Items equipped. Although now that you mention it i'm pretty sure I only found level 61 and 66 yellow ones. The ones that were 62-65 were blue.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In summary, you are going to get level 61/66/70 items as appropriate for your level with the exception of legendary items that scale to your current level. So expect a bit of hardship as you grind from 61 -> 66 as far as rares and blues go.

Blizzard later clarified the confusion in a blue post. I'll leave my original research below but here is the definitive blue post on the matter ([source](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12251125259?page=2#38)):

> It looks like there was a little confusion on this topic, so allow me to
>   clarify - there is not a bug involved here. Required level is not the
>   same thing as an item’s power level, and it definitely does not mean a
>   level 69 character should feel uncomfortable about using an item that
>   specifies “Requires Level 61.” Items saying "Requires Level 61" on
>   them is by design. The item can be at a power level intended for level
>   68 or 69 characters but we let players use it at Level 61 - this is
>   intentional.
>
> A primary boon of this approach is you know that items you find early
>   on in your leveling experience (around 61-62) aren't replaced
>   immediately upon reaching 63. That awesome item you found at 61 should
>   be able to stick with you up through 69. When there are too many tiers
>   of items, you transition through them rapidly and the items start to
>   feel transient. Why bother gemming or enchanting an item if you expect
>   to find an upgrade in 30 minutes? The Mystic’s Enchanting is powerful,
>   but it doesn't feel worth using if you don’t have confidence your item
>   will still be useful in 2 levels. Another benefit of this design
>   choice is that it is alt-friendly. We think it's really fun to have
>   the option to twink characters. Why not allow items you find at the
>   upper echelons of the 60's to be passed down to your new characters
>   fairly easily?
>
> This does have some downsides, including that upgrades can feel a
>   little sparse between the latter levels before cap (66-69). However,
>   in this situation, we felt the benefits outweighed the detriments and
>   it keeps the element of randomness that we feel is core to the Diablo
>   experience. We want to ensure there is a chance to find an amazing top
>   tier item the moment you ding 61 and get to hold on to it for hours if
>   fortune smiles upon you, though that may mean it takes a little longer
>   to find an upgrade for that particular slot.

---

My initial readings made it seem like this was a bug but it appears it is intentional due to the item levels that were added in RoS. Here is a summary of how it is currently working summarized in [this reddit post](http://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/21b25i/am_i_only_supposed_to_be_getting_lvl_61_drops_in/cgbmrzz):

> It's not a bug, it's just a misunderstanding of the loot system. All
>   items have a base item with a specific level requirement, as another
>   response posted, the only items added in ros are at the lvl 61/66/70
>   levels. Those are the only level of items that can drop(ignoring
>   legendaries that out match your level). Once you are past 66 you
>   should mostly or always get lvl 66 items, and at 70 you will get level
>   70 items.
>
> Example:
>
> http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/helm/#type=common
>
> All items that drop are from a base version like this, it looks like
>   many item types don't even have a lvl 66 version.

Here a couple other sources backing it up:

- [Discussion 1 on Diablo 3 Forums](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/10119512742?page=2#23)
- [Reddit Discussion](http://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/21eje1/loot_tables_broken_from_6169/cgcb8qq)
- [Reddit Discussion 2](http://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/21b25i/am_i_only_supposed_to_be_getting_lvl_61_drops_in/cgbc9fp)

Comment: I'll edit in the blue post that confirms it when I find it

Comment: Is there anything to substantiate this comment: http://bit.ly/NTtxsR (that there are only lvl 61, 66, and 70 items in RoS by design)?  If so, that'd explain it pretty simply.

Comment: @tQuarella That's the first comment I've seen to that effect, but you are right that would explain it. I'll try to do some more looking to determine if it is in fact true.

Comment: @tQuarella After some more digging I agree with the posters that this is currently intended, if a bit awkward, for item drops from 61-70.

Answer (score 6):

## It is by design!

There are two tiers of items while leveling from 60-69, at 61 and 66.

**Required Level 61** - These items are actually scaled to be appropriate for anywhere between level 61 and level 65. They just all have a chance at dropping as soon as you reach level 61. This is actually *better* than the old system.

To compare with vanilla Diablo 3, this would be like all gear from levels 51-56 saying "requires level 51" and having a chance of dropping as soon as you reach level 51. This gives you a better chance to find upgrades that will actually stick for a while instead of being replaced every level or two.

**Required Level 66** - Same as above, but for levels 66-69.

The risk with this new system is that you could very well find lots of great gear scaled for level 65 at level 61, and go a long time without any upgrades.

---

I tried to paraphrase this so it was a little more understandable, but here's the explanation in the [words of a blue poster](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12251125259?page=2#38) over on the diablo forums:

> It looks like there was a little confusion on this topic, so allow me to clarify - **There is not a bug involved here.** Required level is not the same thing
> as an item’s power level, and it definitely does not mean a level 69
> character should feel uncomfortable about using an item that specifies
> “Requires Level 61.” Items saying "Requires Level 61" on them is by
> design. The item can be at a power level intended for level 68 or 69
> characters but we let players use it at Level 61 - this is
> intentional.
>
> A primary boon of this approach is you know that items you find early
> on in your leveling experience (around 61-62) aren't replaced
> immediately upon reaching 63. That awesome item you found at 61 should
> be able to stick with you up through 69. When there are too many tiers
> of items, you transition through them rapidly and the items start to
> feel transient. Why bother gemming or enchanting an item if you expect
> to find an upgrade in 30 minutes? The Mystic’s Enchanting is powerful,
> but it doesn't feel worth using if you don’t have confidence your item
> will still be useful in 2 levels. Another benefit of this design
> choice is that it is alt-friendly. We think it's really fun to have
> the option to twink characters. Why not allow items you find at the
> upper echelons of the 60's to be passed down to your new characters
> fairly easily?
>
> This does have some downsides, including that upgrades can feel a
> little sparse between the latter levels before cap (66-69). However,
> in this situation, we felt the benefits outweighed the detriments and
> it keeps the element of randomness that we feel is core to the Diablo
> experience. We want to ensure there is a chance to find an amazing top
> tier item the moment you ding 61 and get to hold on to it for hours if
> fortune smiles upon you, though that may mean it takes a little longer
> to find an upgrade for that particular slot.

Answer (score 1):

Its just bad luck.  My wizard found and used a level 61 weapon until he was level 70.  Though I did find some level 67 stuff that wasn't good.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on a few things.

1) Difficulty

2) RNG

3) Paragon Level

4) Game mode

All of these directly affect how often you get rare loot and how good that item actually is.   RNG will always be RNG but you can increase your chances to find rare loot by increasing difficulty, increasing the number of players in your game, and having a high paragon level.

It's also worth noting that while you're in "story mode" you will rarely find anything of extreme value or quality.  Most of the "top tier" loot is found in Adventure Mode on high difficulty.

If you're having difficulty finding items of your level, try increasing the difficulty and see if that helps.  In the end, and probably most importantly, luck is luck and you can do everything listed above to increase your chances but ultimately RNG will be RNG.

Comment: Are the drops actually altered in Adventure Mode? My understanding is that the same stuff can drop in both, but in Adventure Mode you're just killing more "big" enemies in a more concentrated time, so the rate of good drops increases only as a function of that.

Comment: Right.  It doesn't have an actual affect on your loot chance or anything, but the density of the bigger, tougher monsters, coupled with high paragon level and higher difficulty than normal all allow for more _potential_ better loot to be had. 

As far as I know, adventure mode doesn't give any "better chance" to get anything - as I've seen people get awesome legendaries from both story mode and adventure mode.

Also I'm not sure if these are expanded on in RoS, but key / bounty runs are a great way to get loot too.  UBRS are a great way to get some awesome loot.

Comment: Sorry @Mkalafut, what is RNG? :/

Comment: @Kevdog777: He means the Random Number Generator, the basis of most loot / chance systems in computer gaming

Comment: Sorry @Kevdog777, I should use the actual term next time.  I do mean Random Number Generator, as Rapida has explained.  Everything is random.  Think of it as the game rolling dice behind the scenes to determine if you get loot on any given kill, and then rolling again to determine type and quality.

Comment: Thanks guys. I must've had a very good dice last night, when I was on ... I keep getting legendaries! But the blood shards are useless, it was like the gambler on Diablo 2 :(